# How can I start a session in an app and securely continue it in a browser?

Tags: security, session, access-token

## Requirements

I have to split the user experience across two apps:

1. a downloaded native app
2. the device's default browser

A user will start by logging in to the downloaded app (username/password).  At some point, the user presses a Continue button that launches a browser tab.  I need the user's session to persist in the browser so I can display personalized content without requiring another login.

## Planned Implementation

First the app logs the user in by calling
https://site.com/login?username=USER&password=PASS

... and the server generates a unique session token and replies...

```
{
    "sessionToken": "SWORDFISH"
}
```

Then when the user presses the Continue button, the app instructs the OS to open URL...

https://site.com/page.html?sessionToken=SWORDFISH

## Questions

With sufficiently long and well-distributed session tokens, can this be considered secure?

Is it bad practice to keep the session token in the URL as the user navigates through different pages on site.com?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is Session Fixation attacks.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the keyword.  [Session Fixation wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) has lots of discussion.

Comment: Using POST for the app / browser transfer would be best but I don't know if it is possible. Then remove the sessionToken from the URL after the first request, changing it into a cookie. This reduces shared token / sessions on G+ / email / etc ;)